# Why does htop list so many mysql connections?

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, connection-pooling, htop

Too many mysqld connections are showing when i type htop command.
I'm using mysql pool connection for my project using nodejs sequalize ORM.

[image]

What is the reason it is showing this much connections?

Answer (score 3):

The parent MySQL process spawns multiple *threads* which are shown by [`htop`](https://hisham.hm/htop/) as separate list elements. However, a *thread* is not - per se - associated with an actual *connection*. In general, MySQL itself starts one thread per connection.

To check how many connections are used by MySQL you can run `show full processlist` in a mysql command line shell. For reference see the [documentation of the aforementioned command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-processlist.html).

Note well:

> If you have the `PROCESS` privilege, you can see **all** threads. Otherwise, you can see only your *own* threads (that is, threads associated with the MySQL account that you are using).

Hope it helps.